# SVN problem on OS X: Mismatched RA version

Tags: mac-osx, svn

When I run any svn command on my Mac, I get messages like the following:

```
$svn help
svn: Mismatched RA version for 'neon': found 1.6.2, expected 1.6.5

$svn checkout /some/repo
svn: Mismatched RA version for 'http': found 1.6.2 expected 1.6.5
```

What did I do, and how do I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like not all of your SVN client was upgraded from `1.6.2` to `1.6.5` (namely the `neon` package, which is a HTTP/WebDav library).

A bit of a google on this, [lead me to these instructions](http://wiki.greenstone.org/wiki/index.php/Install_SVN_on_Linux#Install_Neon):

> Check if you have neon by running:
>
> ```
> which neon-config
> ```
>
> If you have neon, a path to
>   neon-config will be outputted.
>   Everything before /bin/neon/config is
>   your neon home directory.
>
> The neon version needs to be 0.25.x or
>   greater. Check the neon version with:
>
> ```
> neon-config --version
> ```
>
> If you have a suitible version of
>   neon, make a note of the neon home
>   directory for use in the last step,
>   Install Subversion Itself.
>
> If you don't have neon, or need to
>   install a newer version, get a recent
>   copy it from the [WebDAV website](http://webdav.org/neon/) in a
>   .tar.gz archive. Install it with:
>
> ```
> cd /research/oranfry/sources
> tar -xzf /path/to/neon-X.X.X.tar.gz
> cd neon-X.X.X
> ./configure --prefix=/research/oranfry/neon make make install
> ```
>
> Remember the neon home directory. In
>   my case it is /research/oranfry/neon.

(your milage may vary, be careful of paths)

Answer (score 1):

If you had installed the Subversion from Collabnet on your Mac, and are getting the above error, you're probably running svn installed with your Mac OS X. Try this command:

```
which svn
```

If you get /usr/bin/svn, that's the old version causing the error.

You need to add this line to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin/:$PATH
```

Log out, log in, and try the which command, it should point to the new version.

NOTE: The Collabnet installer says to put the export command into ~/.profile, however that doesn't seem to work.